# How to identify important categories in categorical variable to predict some binary variable?

Tags: categorical-data, data-mining, predictor

Imagine that we have two sets of data. The first one contains information about websites visited by certain users:

```
USER_ID    WEBSITE_ID
      0             A
      0             C
      0             D
      1             B
      1             D
      2             B
      2             B
      2             C
      3             D
      3             D
```

And another dataset that contains a list of users that performed some specific action. Let's indicate this with a flag:

```
USER_ID          FLAG
      0             0
      1             1
      2             1
      3             0
```

The conclusion one can arrive at is that all users that visited website B at least once, ended up with a flag 1. On the contrary, users who didn't visit website B ended up with a 0.

Now imagine that we have thousands of users and thousands of websites. In this case, it wouldn't be an easy task to perform such a visual inspection. What I want to know is whether there exists some method to be able to know if there are some websites that are in general indicators that users will end up with a flag of value 1 if they visited them. In other words, I want to know if it is possible to come to a conclusion of this sort:

> If a user visited websites A, B, ... (any number of websites), then the user will probably have a flag with value 1.

I basically want to know if some rows of the first dataset can be dropped because they give no information about the flag of the user. In other words, I want to know if it is possible to find a set of values for `WEBSITE_ID` that will help me predict whether the `FLAG` for each user will be 1 or 0.

Is there some approach to achieve this? Sorry if the idea is vague, I tried my best to put it into words. Please let me know if you need me to clarify something.

Comment: Can you not merge the two data sets together, such that you have the flag id in your first data set? Finding which sites have more prevalence of 1's should be easy then.

Comment: @user2974951 But what would happen if a site was visited by all users? That would be the site with the greatest prevalence of 1's, yet it's not very helpful because every user with a 0 flag visited the same site as well. I want to know if there is any method to be able to identify sites that offer information to split 1's and 0's predictively.

Comment: So what is this flag id? What does it represent? Can you link it to a specific user and website? Or can you link it only to a user? If the latter, then how can you determine how the flag came to be? If it has any relation at all with the websites? Do you have any timestamp as to when a user visited websites and when he got a flag?